# how to display extended ascii character in QTextEdit

Tags: c++, qt, unicode, ascii

All the ASCII codes greater than 127 are replaced by Diamond? symbol. How can I display those characters. I have an **unsigned char buffer[1024]** which contains values from 0 to 256.

Comment: There are no ASCII codes greater than 127. Please specify what codes you are talking about.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Have you heard of [Extended ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII)?

Comment: I have actually read the ASCII standard, and I know what I am talking about. “Extended ASCII” is a misnomer for an unspecified collection of characters codes, so asking how to display “extended ASCII” does not make sense. You need to specify what codes you are talking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `QString` class's `fromAscii()` method.  By default this will treat Ascii chars above 128 as Latin-1 chars.  To change this behavior use `QTextCodec::setCodecForCStrings` method to set the correct codec for your usage.

I believe QT5 may have taken out the `setCodecForCStrings` method.

EDIT: Adnan supplied the QT5 alternative to `setCodecForCStrings` method, adding to answer for completeness.

> Qt5 alternative for `setCodecForCStrings` is `QTextCodec::setCodecForLocale(QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8"));`

Comment: For Latin1 there's QString::fromLatin1() and QLatin1String()

Comment: I only mentioned Latin-1 because that is the default behavior of the QString classes fromAscii() method.  I also listed the method to change this behavior (for QT prior to QT5)

Comment: @Josh Qt5 alternative for setCodecForCStrings is QTextCodec::setCodecForLocale(QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8")); Thanks!

Comment: It is important to realise that although the Unicode *codepoint* numbers for the Latin1 encoding is a one to one match for those in the range 128 to 255 this does not mean that the UTF-8 representation of those characters (in bytes) is NOT the same as the Latin1 *extended* ASCII encoding...!

Answer (score 1):

This is a rabbit hole with no end.  Qt does not fully support printing ascii > 127 as it is not well defined.  The current method is to use "fromLocal8bit()" which will take a char array and transform it into the "right" Unicode string (the only thing Qt supports printing).

QTextCodec::setCodecForLocale can be used to identify the character set you wish to transform from.  Many codecs are supported, but for some reason IBM437 (the character set used by IBM PCs in the US for decades) is not supported, where several other codecs used by Europe, etc. are.  Probably some characters in IBM437 were never assigned proper code points in Unicode, so transforming it isn't possible?

What's frustrating is that there are fonts with all 256 ascii code points, but it is simply not possible to display these in Qt as they only work with Unicode strings.  There are a handful of glyphs they don't support, and it seems to grow with newer versions of Qt.  Currently I know of 9, 10, 12, 13, and 173.  Some of these are for obvious reasons (usually you don't want to print a carriage return glyph, though it did exist in DOS), but others used to work in Qt and now do not.

In my application, I resorted to creating a new font that has copies of the unprintable glyphs in higher unicode codepoints, and translate them before printing them on the screen.  It's quite silly but Qt gave up on ascii many years ago, so it's the best option I could find.

Comment: Having just added support for that encoding to a project using Qt 5.14.2 I can assure you that there is a `QTextCodec` for **CP437**, it reports as aliases: `ibm-437_P100-1995`, `ibm-437`, `cp437`, `437`, `csPC8CodePage437` and `windows-437`.

Comment: @SlySven, can you create a textedit displaying all 254 glyphs from CP437?  I admit I haven't tried in a while.  But last I checked, it was not possible to draw 9,10,12,13 and 173.  For 173 (0xad) see line 987 of https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/dev/util/unicode/main.cpp.

Comment: @SlySven, it is not a supported codec listed here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextcodec.html -- however, ICU support probably adds it.

Comment: Yeah, I found out that my Linux (Debian) and WIndows (MSYS) OS's Qt libraries uses ICU but the Windows (Qt's own build) that my F.O.S.S. project's CI process (which also builds the binaries that we hand out) doesn't. Since I last commented I have built my own `QTextCodec` derived class to provide a CP437 codec and it is *largely* functional but has some obvious gaps, probably around the backspace, horizontal and vertical tabs, line-feed and carriage return, backspace and delete ASCII codes. OTOH as my project will talk to another system some characters have to be reserved...

Comment: ... so it isn't an exactly fair and complete comparison but I can live with those omissions (and can recommend that users who want all of them use a different encoding that CAN convey all of them - which is of course UTF-8).

Comment: fair enough.  I have an application where I use all glyphs, and I could never make Qt work with them using a 256-character ascii font.  Win32 can do it, though, so it's just a limitation in Qt's abstraction to UTF-8 that those codepoints become lost.  9,10 & 13 I can understand, but the others used to work and were broken later.